# How to push object into an object array in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-forms

I have an empty object array like this `groupList:any = {}` and now I want to push an object into it. I am trying to name and description as an object.

Comment: `groupList` is not an array here, it is just a plain old object. I suspect there is some confusion caused by calling that an "object array". I think this could be cleared up with an example - can you include in the question what this should look like if there were multiple objects stored in `groupList`?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: hey oliver, could you mark the answer?

Answer (score 9):

It is not an array, array is represented like [] , probably you need

```
groupList:any = [];
```

and then,

```
this.groupList.push({name:'you',description:'what is array'});
```

Comment: yes, it is not an array but i am trying to push into it using angular form to get the following structure:  `"groupList": {
{"name":group1","description":"descrption1"}
}`

Comment: @OliverQueen The JSON you have written is not valid, you cannot just have an object inside another object like that. An object is composed of property names and values, so you cannot have an "unnamed" property like that. Are you, perhaps, mixing this up with a dictionary? eg `"groupList": { "group1": "description1", "group2": "description2" }`

Answer (score 1):

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
    groupList:any = [];
    arrayVal:any;
    currentVal : any;
  title = 'projectchart';
  public array = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}];

 getPrev(){

     this.array.forEach((item, index) => {

  this.groupList.push(item.id);

});
console.log(this.groupList); 
 }


}
```

### app.component.html

```
<button (click) ="getVal()">Previous Value</button>
```